# Regular expression formatting issue

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm VERY new to using regular expressions, and I'm trying to figure something simple out.

I have a simple string, and i'm trying to pull out the 590111 and place it into another string.

```
HMax_590111-1_v8980.bin
```

So the new string would simply be...

```
590111
```

The part number will ALWAYS have 6 digits, and ALWAYS have a version and such. The part number might change location inside of the string.. so it needs to be able to work if it's like this..

```
590111-1_v8980_HMXAX.bin
```

What regex expression will do this? Currently, i'm using `^[0-9]*` to find it if it's in the front of the file.

Comment: try this regex [\d]{6}. let me know if you need code for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following Regex:

```
Dim text As String = "590111-1_v8980_HMXAX.bin"
Dim pattern As String = "\d{6}"

'Instantiate the regular expression object.
Dim r As Regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

'Match the regular expression pattern against a text string.
Dim m As Match = r.Match(text)
```

In Regex **\d** denotes numerics, so first you write `\d`.

Then as you know there will be a fix length of numbers which can be specified in Regex with **"{}"**. If you specify **\d{6}** it means it will expect 6 continuous occurrences of a numeric character.

I would recommend to use this site to try your own expressions. Here you can also find a little bit of information about the expressions you are building if you hover over it.

[**Regex Tester**](http://www.regextester.com/)

Comment: This works wonderfully, I can accept it as the answer in 7 minutes (stack tells me this), could you explain what the reg expression is doing? :)